# Python one-liner into normal for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I am trying to understand the following one-liner:
`weights = [0.0 for i in range(len(training_data[0]))]`

I would like to understand what that *actually* says. I think it says
Append a [0.0] to the `weights` list for every `i` in the range of the length of `training_data[0]`

I need to convert that one-liner to a normal for loop. The following does not yield the same result, as the program I editing later complains about a numpy problem:

```
weights = []
num_rows = training_data[0]
for index in range(len(num_rows)):
    weights.append([0.0])
```

Any advice on how to convert the one-liner to a normal looking for loop is appreciated.

Comment: Close. `weights.append(0.0)`, not `weights.append([0.0])`.

Comment: What error is shown by numpy?

Comment: You edited and fixed your own code in the question. Never do that as the question has no value for future user now.

Comment: Show us the traceback. You are giving no information about the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a list comprehension, basically you convert it like this:

```
weights = [0.0 for i in range(len(training_data[0]))]
```

into:

```
weights = []
total_iterations = len(training_data[0])
for i in range(total_iterations): # equivalent to for i==0, i<total_iterations, i++ in other languages
    weights.append(0.0)
```